# How to change transaction name dynamically using variable/parameter file in Neoload

Tags: neoload

I want to change the transaction name dynamically. For example, I am running the script for 5 iteration and every iteration I am using different values from the parameter. So for every iteration I want to change the transaction name based on the value I am using.

I tried to pass the variable name but it is throwing error.
[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I;m also looking at this but can't figure it out